# cast from IFeatureClass to ISchemaLock (ARCGIS)

Tags: java, arcgis

I'm programming with the ARCGIS Java SDK, in Eclipse.

I need to cast an **IFeatureClass** to an **ISchemalock**. This cast is supposed to be allowed. There is an example of this cast in: 
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/b22267cb-642c-11dc-9ca3-0b35f906bb2e.htm

However, when I try to perform this cast in my code, an exception appears:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IFeatureClassProxy cannot be cast to com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.ISchemaLock*

Are you able to make this cast on an IFeatureClass ? Here is the code to perform this:

```
//Attempt to acquire an exclusive schema lock on the feature class.
ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)featureClass;
```

I would appreciate if you could try this simple line of code in one of your programs.

Keep me posted...

Comment: Is the class of the `featureClass` object really implement both interfaces?

Comment: `IFeatureClassProxy`, which is actually a class despite the preceding `I`, doesn't implement `ISchemaLock`. Why do you have an `IFeatureClassProxy` object instead of `FeatureClass`?